# How to parse a string into a csv in python

Tags: python, pandas, csv, parsing

I have a str with data the looks like

```
2013/04/15, 54332, 2013/04/16, 67608, 2013/04/17, 56535, 2013/04/18, 46484
```

where there is a date and then a value, how would I get this into a csv with columns for both the date and values? I tried doing this:

```
df = pd.Dataframe(list(reader(data)))
df.to_csv('Data.csv', index=False)
```

but when I do that it puts one character of the string on each line and in only one column.

Comment: review documentation for python built in function split, to turn your comma-separated string into a list. Then you can solve your problem with list iteration.

Answer (score 1):

The following should work:

```
import pandas as pd

l=[i.strip() for i in s.split(',')]
dates=[l[i] for i in range(0,len(l),2)]
values=[l[i] for i in range(1,len(l),2)]

df=pd.DataFrame({'date':dates, 'value': values})

>>> print(df)

         date    value
0  2013/04/15  54332
1  2013/04/16  67608
2  2013/04/17  56535
3  2013/04/18  46484
```

Then you can save it as csv file, like below:

```
df.to_csv('Data.csv', index=False)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following:

```
data = data.replace(' ', '').split(',')
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': data[::2], 'Value': data[1::2]})
```

Output:

```
         Date  Value
0  2013/04/15  54332
1  2013/04/16  67608
2  2013/04/17  56535
3  2013/04/18  46484
```

Comment: why `replace()` and not simply `split(', ')` - i.e. with comma and space?

Comment: Nice suggestion @buran! Although `split(', ')` works well for this sample data, it may not work if any of the spaces is absent (or with more than one space). Using `replace` avoids such issues.

Comment: Your code is supposed to work with sample data, provided by OP. They should point out if there is possibility to get different input. If we keep the same line of reasoning - what if there is a semi-colon instead of comma, or break in the pattern date-value? Just my 2 cents.

Comment: It works for the sample data. I used to work with csv files, and it's quite common issues with white spaces between commas, and far less common such other issues. That's why I wrote that (habit with dealing with white spaces).

Comment: That said, I totally agree that using `split(', ')` works as well, and it also makes the code cleaner (what I think it's important as well). Feel free to edit the answer if you want.